# Tikz 2 circles with arrows pointing at each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

how can I get the arrow style to "-> <-" instead of -> ?

[image]

```
\node [circle, draw, fill=red] (b1) at (0,0) {};
\node [circle, draw, fill=red] (b2) at (1,0) {};
\draw[->,thick] (b1) -- (b2);
```

Comment: arrow style or you want the lines meet each other?

Comment: i added a picture to illustrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,> = stealth]
\node [circle, draw, fill=red] (b1) at (0,0) {};
\node [circle, draw, fill=red] (b2) at (1,0) {};
\path (b1) edge[->,thick] ($(b1)!0.5!(b2)$) 
      ($(b1)!0.5!(b2)$) edge[<-,thick] (b2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]